# Нужна ли запятая в стихотворении Маяковского и в учебнике Розенталя при обособлении вставки?

Tags: вставная-конструкция

1. Предложение из стихотворения Маяковского, оно же приводится у Розенталя.  Я полагаю, что нужна вторая запятая при обособлении вставки.

*Мне бы жить и жить,
сквозь годы мчась.
Но в конце хочу –
**других желаний нету** –
встретить я хочу
мой смертный час
так,
как встретил смерть
товарищ Нетте.*

2. Предложение из учебника Розенталя (отредактированный текст Лескова). Также, мне кажется, нужна вторая запятая при обособлении вставки, а запятой нет. Ошибка (**если это ошибка**) тиражируется на учебных сайтах. У Розенталя возможна опечатка, а остальные педагоги списывают? Не хотелось бы, конечно, так думать.

*Выскочила я на минуточку на улицу – **тут у нас в нашем же доме под низом кондитерская** – взяла десять штучек песочного пирожного...* (Леск.)

Answer (score 2):

*Но в конце хочу, встретить я хочу...* || Запятая обязательна перед повторением слова "хочу". Вставка относится к первой части. Соответственно, запятая нужна после вставки.

*Выскочила я на минуточку на улицу, взяла десять штучек песочного пирожного...* || Запятая перед однородным сказуемым. Вставка относится к первой части. Соответственно, запятая после вставки.

Но здесь лучше оформление, что вторая часть является следствием первой. Тогда ставим тире:
*Выскочила я на минуточку на улицу — (и как результат/следствие) взяла десять штучек песочного пирожного...* || Тогда имеем наложение двух тире после вставки и остаётся одно.

Может, и у Маяковского между частями было интонационное тире, а не запятая.

Возможно, что на тот момент правило о вставных конструкциях ещё не было выведено и авторы полагали, что тире может заменять запятую.

Comment: Значит, обе запятые нужны, это совершенно очевидно. В первом случае идет повтор сказуемого, во втором - однородные сказуемые. Обе запятые структурные, перенесенные, куда без них?  У Лескова было более сложное предложение,вот его и "отредактировали", править его лучше не надо: Выскочила я на минуточку на улицу - тут у нас, в вашем же доме, под низом кондитерская, - взяла десять штучек песочного пирожного. Ну а почему допускаются такие ошибки?

Comment: Ну если в оригинале стоит запятая, то и после редактирования сохранить её - дело чести. Почему допускаются... Или из-за невнимательности, или из-за незнания. Одно из двух.

Comment: Дело не в этом, структура предложения после редактирования изменилась, поэтому ставить знаки нужно в измененном предложении по существующим правилам. А причина еще хуже, чем невнимательность или незнание. Это полное нежелание думать и критически оценивать материал. Если педагоги не думают, то что говорить о детях.

Comment: Отсутствие запятой у Маяковского можно оправдать только как сохранение авторской пунктуации. Но тогда зачем включать такой текст в учебные материалы?

Comment: Согласен. Но, может, у него там было интонационное тире или многоточие вместо запятой. Даже если так, то включать в учебные материалы спорные случаи крайне нежелательно, по крайней мере, без их разъяснения.

Comment: У Розенталя ясно сказано: 1) с обеих сторон ставится только тире, если в месте вставки  не должно быть никакого знака препинания. Нарушение этого правила я считаю грубой ошибкой. У Маяковского можно списать на особое оформление стихотворной речи, но только как исключение. Хорошо бы у Грамоты спросить, но мне они больше не отвечают.

Comment: Думаю, что имеется в виду запятая - другой знак же не может превратится в запятую. Можно на Грамме спросить, как Серж предлагает. У Грамоты слишком много вопросов, и читал, что они отвечают подряд (даже на глупые), но до какого-то количества за определённый период, может, по мере успеваемости.

Comment: О  чем вы? В исходном предложении на месте вставки нет знаков, если мы ставим только два тире, например: Кругом — не обнять глазом — снежная пелена (Ш.); Аннушка молча покинула свою засаду, тихо обошла кругом — её детские ножки едва шумели по густой траве — и вышла из чащи подле самого старика (Т.); Поэтому убираем вставку и проверяем исходное предложение.

Comment: Грамма - это не такой авторитетный сайт, как Грамота. Там частные вопросы можно обсуждать, а здесь тема общезначимая: Розенталь все-таки, Маяковский.

Comment: Я о том, что если между частями тире или не запятая, то и запятых при вставке не будет. || Серж мне ответил, что на Грамме ответы профессиональнее, так как Грамота избегает сложных вопросов. Не знаю... Попробуйте повторно спрашивать, если не будет ответа.

Comment: Если на месте вставки не было запятой, то ставится два тире. А если были другие знаки, кроме запятой, то такое оформление (только два тире) не допускается вообще. "При постановке только двух тире в исходном предложении (если убрать вставку) НИКАКИХ знаков препинания не разрешено" (Розенталь).

Comment: Но если было тире, а не запятая, то два тире не поставим и остаётся одно. А такое может быть часто.

Comment: Вы не забыли, что мы обособляем вставку, которая в середине предложения ВСЕГДА  обособляется ДВУМЯ тире. Других вариантов здесь нет, два тире уже поставлены.  Одно тире будете ставить в других случаях, а мы обсуждаем этот.

Comment: Имею в виду совсем другое. Что причиной отсутствия запятой может быть то, что у автора по плану тире между частями, а не запятая. Раз запятой не было, то и при вставке её не будет. А про два тире имел в виду, что два подряд не может стоять (в итоге три).

Comment: Ладно, диспут закончен. Вы бы лучше не пространные описания приводили, которые понять невозможно,  а конкретные примеры. Переписали бы Маяковского, убрав вставку, вот тогда это было бы убедительно и понятно. Но это уже в другой раз.

Comment: У Маяковского там не получается. Разве что интонационное тире вместо запятой. А вот у Лескова получается - следственные отношения между частями (в ответе это обозначил).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что Розенталь в обоих случаях мысленно применяет свой универсальный приём: что получается в результате *изъятия оборота* в виде отвлечённой вставки? В первом случае остаётся, скорее всего, многоточие, во втором может стоять тире вместо запятой, а два тире подряд не бывает, что позволяет избежать сдвоенного знака. У меня такой подход возражения не вызывает.

Comment: Многоточие не подходит, так как "других желаний нету" указывает на то, что мысль уже была сформирована.

Comment: Запятая была бы в случае: "я хочу, хочу встретить...", но здесь _сбивчивый_ порядок слов, даже "я" вдогонку двум глаголам появляется. Мысль переформулирована.

Comment: Alex_ander. 1) Убираем вставку из первого предложения: Но в конце хочу встретить я хочу... И что это  без запятой получается? 2)  Убираем вставку из второго предложения: Выскочила я на минуточку взяла десять штучек песочного пирожного... И где запятая между сказуемыми?

Comment: Но в конце хочу... [о чём это я?] встретить я хочу! Выскочила я на минуточку [не случайно, а вот зачем:] - взяла десять штучек песочного пирожного...

Comment: При постановке только двух тире в исходном предложении (если убрать вставку) НИКАКИХ знаков препинания не разрешено (Розенталь). А у Вас многоточие какое-то или тире. Ничего нельзя.